# How to pass a cancel reason to .Net Task

Tags: .net

.Net Task supports [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx), but I want to pass a reason for the cancel. In my situation, my Task is canceled some reason, and the Task has to finish a different way every reason of the cancellation.

CancellationTokenSource class hasn't some property for set that reason.
How to pass a cancel reason to Task?

Comment: As you say, `Task` cancellation doesn't support any extra data. You will have to write some code yourself to share this state.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a reason or message to a `Task` to indicate the reason.

The way that `Task` instances (or other operations) are cancelled is by passing around [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384802.aspx) instances which can be checked/registered with to determine whether or not the operation has been cancelled (this is the "cooperative" aspect of task cancellation).

However, cancellations are *not* able to be affected from the `CancellationToken`, they are affected from the [`CancellationTokenSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx) which created them through calls to the various [`Cancel` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321955.aspx) overloads.

Also, when a task is cancelled, an exception that derives from [`OperationCancelledException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx) is thrown, which you can catch.  When you catch that exception, you can take a look at the [`CancellationToken` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.cancellationtoken.aspx); this exposes the `CancellationToken` that was used to cancel the operation.

From there, you can pass it to the [override of the `Equals` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd384804.aspx) on the `CancellationToken` structure exposed by the [`Token` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.token.aspx); if the call to `Equals` returns true, then the operation was cancelled by that `CancellationTokenSource` which you can associate with the reasons for cancellation.

Note that you'll probably have to dig through the exceptions contained in an [`AggregateException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx), as most exceptions thrown from asynchronous operations are wrapped in that.

Comment: Nicholas said in above comment, CancellationTokenSource hasn't any method for some cancellation reason. So I'll try to make own class for share the reason between a Task and the canceler.